# jQuery: change a div's id twice not working

Tags: jquery, html, click

I've been trying to toggle a div's id when the user clicks on it.
First click works, and it changes the divs id, but when pressing again it wont change the div's id again....

```
$("#hello").click(function(){
    $(this).attr("id","bye").text("bye");
});

$("#bye").click(function(){
    $(this).attr("id","hello").text("hello");
});

<div id="hello">hello</div>
```

Any ideas of how to get this working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The handler is assigned to the element when the document loads, so there's no handler assigned to `bye` since there's no element.

You can use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (note that [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is better if there's some ancestor it can be applied to.):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/Pwa5Q/2/

```
$("#hello").live('click',function(){
    $(this).attr("id","bye").text("bye");
});

$("#bye").live('click',function(){
    $(this).attr("id","hello").text("hello");
});
```

Or just assign the handler to the element with `hello`, and use the same handler to toggle the ID.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/Pwa5Q/

```
$("#hello").click(function(){
    var newID = this.id === 'hello' ? 'bye' : 'hello';
    $(this).attr("id",newID).text(newID);
});
```

Comment: I would prefer the second solution by far. Simpler code, less work for the client browser, and properly links the two actions.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because click event handler for 'bye' is bound before div's id is set to 'bye' in DOM. You can use [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to get around this:

```
$("#hello").live('click', function(){
    $(this).attr("id","bye").text("bye");
});

$("#bye").live('click', function(){
    $(this).attr("id","hello").text("hello");
});
```